# CSS media print textarea does not appear at the top of the page

Tags: css, print-preview

I have an textarea that I want to be able to print. I wrote the following CSS fragment:

```
  @media print {
  body * {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  .printable, .printable * {
    visibility: visible;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
}
```

When I try to print the text box appears about half way down the page and it's only 4 lines high and very narrow. I tried everything I could think off (specifying height & width, etc) but nothing seem to work.

Does anyone know why is the text area appearing half way down the page and how to fix it?

Comment: Try adding `body {position:relative;}`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but it didn't work.

Comment: In that case can you share the relevant markup? Please provide an mcve: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @nvioli As far as I can tell, there is nothing that's relevant, just a textarea in the a bunch of nested divs. Would it better to post the CSS?

Comment: I still think the problem probably has to do with your `absolute` positioning and missing a `relative` parent, but without a reproduction of the problem, I and anyone else on here will just be guessing. Please read the previously linked article and provide an example that shows the problem. Until you do that there's really no way anyone can help you.